# How to create new property dynamically

Tags: php, object, properties

How can I create a property from a given argument inside a object's method?

```
class Foo{

  public function createProperty($var_name, $val){
    // here how can I create a property named "$var_name"
    // that takes $val as value?

  }

}
```

And I want to be able to access the property like:

```
$object = new Foo();
$object->createProperty('hello', 'Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii');

echo $object->hello;
```

Also is it possible that I could make the property public/protected/private ? I know that in this case it should be public, but I may want to add some magik methods to get protected properties and stuff :)

---

I think I found a solution:

```
  protected $user_properties = array();

  public function createProperty($var_name, $val){
    $this->user_properties[$var_name] = $val;

  }

  public function __get($name){
    if(isset($this->user_properties[$name])
      return $this->user_properties[$name];

  }
```

do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: Questions should never be edited to insert a "solution" -- that's what answers are for.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

There are two methods to doing it.

One, you can directly create property dynamically from outside the class:

```
class Foo{

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->hello = 'Something';
```

Or if you wish to create property through your `createProperty` method:

```
class Foo{
    public function createProperty($name, $value){
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->createProperty('hello', 'something');
```

Comment: thank you. I need it inside the class though. It's kind of complicated to explain, the properties are actually objects which are site extensions that the site administrator can enable/disable :) But I will use my solution, I think it's better to keep them inside an array.

Comment: Is it possible to set them as private or protectd?

Comment: Setting property like this does not allow us to make it private or protected because it is set from public. However, you can try to work with OOP magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713680/php-get-and-set-magic-methods

Comment: Your second method of dynamic property creation will result in `Notice: Undefined variable: name ` Please check it

Comment: I think sun is right on this one. The line `$this->$name = $value;` should actually be `$this->name = $value;`

Comment: Or `$this->{$name} = $value;`, no?

Comment: If you want a dynamic property name like in this case we  want the hello attribute then use ``$this->{$name}`` istead of ``$this->name`` cause ``$this->name`` will only create a name property

Comment: The first solution is deprecated in [PHP 8.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.deprecated.php)
`class Foo{} $foo = new Foo(); $foo->hello = 'Something';`

Answer (score 26):

The following example is for those who do not want to declare an entire class.

```
$test = (object) [];

$prop = 'hello';

$test->{$prop} = 'Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii';

echo $test->hello; // prints Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

Answer (score 7):

Property overloading is very slow. If you can, try to avoid it. Also important is to implement the other two magic methods:

__isset();
__unset();

If you don't want to find some common mistakes later on when using these object "attributes"

Here are some examples:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

EDITED after Alex comment:

You can check yourself the differences in time between both solutions (change $REPEAT_PLEASE)

```
<?php

 $REPEAT_PLEASE=500000;

class a {}

$time = time();

$a = new a();
for($i=0;$i<$REPEAT_PLEASE;$i++)
{
$a->data = 'hi';
$a->data = 'bye'.$a->data;
}

echo '"NORMAL" TIME: '.(time()-$time)."\n";

class b
{
        function __set($name,$value)
        {
                $this->d[$name] = $value;
        }

        function __get($name)
        {
                return $this->d[$name];
        }
}

$time=time();

$a = new b();
for($i=0;$i<$REPEAT_PLEASE;$i++)
{
$a->data = 'hi';
//echo $a->data;
$a->data = 'bye'.$a->data;
}

echo "TIME OVERLOADING: ".(time()-$time)."\n";
```

Comment: I'm kind of addicted to __get / __set / __call. I practically use them in every class to get nice API when using that class ... Didn't need __isset so far.. Can you provide a link or something with some benchmarks related to overloading?

Comment: Sorry for the bad news but __call is really slow too

Comment: Show some references/evidence to "property overloading is slow".

Comment: @Pacerier use the benchmark code I put in my answer and check the time spent for both solutions in your own servers

Answer (score 6):

Use the syntax: $object->{$property}
              where $property is a string variable and 
              $object can be this if it is inside the class or any instance object

Live example:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/108f0ca2bef5cf4af8225d6a6ff11dfd0741757f

```
 class Test{
    public function createProperty($propertyName, $propertyValue){
        $this->{$propertyName} = $propertyValue;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->createProperty('property1', '50');
echo $test->property1;
```

Result: 50

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, I already new that you can just reference properties in objects that haven't previously been declared... $object->example = "hello"; I was more after how do you dynamically add the property to object whilst also dynamically specifying what you want to call the property.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**

DO NOT EVER USE DYNAMIC PROPERTIES!!!
IT TS BAD DESING OF YOUR CODE.

Since php 8.2 dynamic properties are deprecated

More about it - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.deprecated.php

Create every property in class in advance. It might help you to avoid mistakes and confusions in future developing and help edit and scale your code faster.

Example

```
<?php
class User {
    public int $userid;
}
$user = new User();
$user->userid = 1234;
echo $user->userid;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).