# (PHP) Declare class properties via loop

Tags: php

I would like to use a loop to create properties inside a class.

```
class Example           
{
    for( $i=0; $i<5; $i++ )  
    {   
    public $num . $i;
    }

}
```

When I do this I get the error

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Am I understanding this completely wrong or is it a syntax error? Thanks

Comment: Rule #1 Don't number variables; if you have numbered variables, then you should probably be using an array instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Rule #2 Your understanding is completely wrong... a class comprises functions/methods and properties.... you can't have code outside of a function/property... if you want to dynamically define properties, then define the in the constructor method code; but you define them by assigning a value to them, and they can never be anything other than public

Comment: Class example {public  $num;for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)  {$num+=$i}  }

Comment: Have you considered having an array as a class member instead?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `public $x;` is a declaration (even when a default value is provided for the property) and it is handled during the compilation phase while a [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) statement is code and it is executed when the script runs (this means **after** and **only if** the code is compiled successfully).

Comment: You  can't do what you're trying to do. Seek other alternatives. Also,if it's just 5 variables declare them explicitely, it will save you a lot of headaches later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the constructor to achieve this:

```
class Example           
{
   public function __Construct(){
      for( $i=0; $i<5; $i++ )  
      {   
       public $this->{'num' . $i};
      }
    }

}
```

In constructor you can perform the action. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#example-193).

Another way to achieve this is:

```
class Example           
{
  public $num = array();
   public function fun(){
      for( $i=0; $i<5; $i++ )  
      {   
        $this->num[$i] = 'value';
      }
    }

}
```

Take the variable as array.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to loop in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of the class:

```
class Example{
    public function __construct(){
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
            $this->{'num' . $i} = $i;
    }
}
```

Then you simply create a new instance of Example:

```
$obj = new Example();
```

Which would give you an object like this:

```
object(Example)#1 (5) {
  ["num0"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["num2"]=>
  int(2)
  ["num3"]=>
  int(3)
  ["num4"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is wrong sytax. **You can't have anything directly in class except methods or properties declaration.**

To create dynamic properties follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8707277/2219158)

Something like this ([Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907450/2219158))

```
class Test{
    public function createProperty($propertyName, $propertyValue){
        $this->{$propertyName} = $propertyValue;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->createProperty('property1', '50');
echo $test->property1;
```