# How to use own setter/getter with Idiorm/Paris?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, getter-setter, idiorm

I have a model (php class) and a table in my database. When I try to `find_many` without a where clause, it finds all database entries. And it creates a model for each of the database entries. But these models are empty and have no data assigned because I have my own setter/getter for my model.

```
<?php

class City extends Model {

    private $id;
    private $idOwm;
    private $idBla;
    private $name;
    private $longitude;
    private $latitude;
    private $country;

    public function data() {
        return $this->has_many('Data', 'idCity');
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getIdOwm() {
        return $this->idOwm;
    }

    public function setIdOwm($idOwm) {
        $this->idOwm = $idOwm;
    }

    public function getIdBla() {
        return $this->idBla;
    }

    public function setIdBla($idBla) {
        $this->idBla = $idBla;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getLongitude() {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude($longitude) {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function getLatitude() {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude($latitude) {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }

    public function getCountry() {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry($country) {
        $this->country = $country;
    }
}

$cities = Model::factory('City')->find_many();
```

`$cities` is an array with many models of type `City`.

```
City Object
(
    [id:protected] => 
    [idOwm:protected] => 
    [idBla:protected] => 
    [name:protected] => 
    [longitude:protected] => 
    [latitude:protected] => 
    [country:protected] => 
    [orm] => ORM Object
        (
            [_connection_name:protected] => default
            [_table_name:protected] => city
            [_table_alias:protected] => 
            [_values:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_result_columns:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => *
                )

            [_using_default_result_columns:protected] => 1
            [_join_sources:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_distinct:protected] => 
            [_is_raw_query:protected] => 
            [_raw_query:protected] => 
            [_raw_parameters:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_where_conditions:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_limit:protected] => 
            [_offset:protected] => 
            [_order_by:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_group_by:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_having_conditions:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [idOwm] => 2950159
                    [idBla] => 0
                    [name] => Berlin
                    [latitude] => 52.52
                    [longitude] => 13.41
                    [country] => DE
                )

            [_dirty_fields:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_expr_fields:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_is_new:protected] => 
            [_instance_id_column:protected] => id
        )

)
```

**How can I use my own setter/getter with Idiorm/Paris? Is this possible or will I have to do some model logic in a different way?**

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this as Idiorm relies on the `__set()` and `__get()` magic methods - if you include proper class properties of the same name then those magic methods will never be accessed. See the [PHP manual<sup>docs link</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for more detail on this.

To get your IDE working you can probably use [PHPDoc `@property` comments<sup>docs link</sup>](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html), which is designed for this purpose. I don't actually use PHPStorm, but from what I can see in its documentation it does understand PHPDoc comments and can use them for understanding code structure.

So your code would look like this:

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $idOwm
 * @property int $idBla
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $longitude
 * @property string $latitude
 * @property string $country
 */
class City extends Model {

    public function data() {
        return $this->has_many('Data', 'idCity');
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ...
}
```

This other stackoverflow question and answer suggests that this will work in Netbeans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15160464/461813

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I remove my private/protected class variables at the top of my models it works.

```
<?php

class City extends Model {

    public function data() {
        return $this->has_many('Data', 'idCity');
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getIdOwm() {
        return $this->idOwm;
    }

    public function setIdOwm($idOwm) {
        $this->idOwm = $idOwm;
    }

    public function getIdBla() {
        return $this->idBla;
    }

    public function setIdBla($idBla) {
        $this->idBla = $idBla;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getLongitude() {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude($longitude) {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function getLatitude() {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude($latitude) {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }

    public function getCountry() {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry($country) {
        $this->country = $country;
    }
}

$cities = Model::factory('City')->find_many();
```

I guess it is really handy to have the variables there to use code generation of PHPStorm, but then you should delete them.