# Object property does not seem to work as variable function?

Tags: php

Iam working on sample codes in php, I read the variable functions (which is kind of similar to function pointers in C) and started to write below code. Take a look at this

```
 class fruit{
     public $run;
 }

 function ano1(){
    // some statements
 }

 $x = 'ano1'; // variable function
 $x(); // works

 $f = new fruit;
 $f->run = 'ano1'; // lets store function to $run property
 $f->run(); // call to undefined method why?
```

**Reason I think**
  because it needs `$this` reference to be passed implicitly to `ano1()` which is not a member function? So using $this is not valid inside `ano1()` they simply did not implement it yet? But Iam a c++ background which is quite possible in c++:

```
class fruit{ 
   public : void (*run) ();
};

void ano1(){ cout << "im running" << endl; }

int main(){
  fruit f;
  f.run = ano1;
  f.run(); // works as long as you dont use this
}
```

Or is there a workaround in php as well? (Without closures and anonymous functions). Thank you

Comment: Workaround requires the magic `__set()` and `__get()` methods : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713680/php-get-and-set-magic-methods ... but only with class members - PHP doesn't really do method overloading as such, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works entirely differently than function pointers in C.

The particular reason for the error message you're seeing is that PHP cannot tell the difference between `$fruit->run()` and `$fruit->run()`; that is, the difference between *calling the method `run` of `$fruit`*, and *calling whatever function name `$fruit->run` evaluates to.* And it errs on the wrong side of what you expect. You can disambiguate with `call_user_func($fruit->run)`.

PHP doesn't have anything like "function pointers". Functions are second class citizens in PHP. `$x` merely holds a string, and PHP's way of supporting passing functions around is to pass them by name. When attempting to "call a string", PHP will instead check if there's a function of that name, and call it instead.

So what you're doing is you're merely assigning a string to an object property, but PHP's syntax is too ambiguous to allow you to call it from there. It is not possible at all <sub>(with any sort of *sane* code)</sub> to graft a function onto an object after the fact. All object methods must be defined in the class of the object instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because doing `$f->run()` says 'call the `run` method of the `$f` object'.

Instead, you could do:

```
$str = $f->run;
$str();
```

which invokes the string as a function call.
Or

```
 $f = new fruit;
 $f->run = 'ano1';
 call_user_func($f->run)
```

which then simply invokes the property `run` as a method

A way that you could... sort of automate that is by using magic method [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) like so:

```
class Fruit {

    public $run;

    public function __call($methodName,$argsArray){

        if (property_exists($this,$methodName)
                &&is_callable($this->$methodName)){
            return call_user_func_array($this->$methodName,$argsArray);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Method {$methodName} does not exist");
        }

    }
}
```

Then, you would do:

```
$fruit = new Fruit();
$fruit->run = 'ano1';
$fruit->run();
```

Then `run` is not defined in the class `Fruit`, so it passes the method name (run) to `__call` with any arguments you passed to `run`. Then if `Fruit` has a property named `$methodName` (in this case 'run'), and the property can be called as a function, then use `call_user_func_array` to invoke it as a function.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code

```
$f->{$f->run}();
```

Since your was treating a run() method on a object of class fruit

Comment: `Call to undefined method fruit::ano1()`

Comment: Sorry i assumed that it was inside the class you can use call_user_func($f->run)